# Swift AVFoundation metadataoutput func run more than 10 times ?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, metadata

at my app working on Ean-13 barcode scanning and it works fine but at code metedataoutpu functions works more than 10 times here is my code:

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count != 0 {
        if let object = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
            if object.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13 {
                var productID = ""
                productID = object.stringValue!
                 print(productID)
              }
         }
    }
}
```